Cloudflare workers cron job to call a honojs api endpoint on same workers domain
I have two coudflare workers: API and CRON.
API is a simple HonoJS API:
import { Hono } from "hono";

const app = new Hono();

app.get("/hello", (c) => {
  // do stuff, including async tasks.
  return c.text("Hello Hono!");
});

export default app;

In my CRON worker, I would like to call the /hello endpoint every day.
When I try to use fetch, I get a 1042 error, which upon further investigation tells me that I cannot call one worker from another worker, and I should use service bindings.
The cloudflare documentation says a service binding should be created like this:
import { WorkerEntrypoint } from "cloudflare:workers";

export class WorkerB extends WorkerEntrypoint {
  async add(a, b) { return a + b; }
}

I don't understand how to translate this over to my HonoJS instance, which I can't find any documentation for using service bindings with.
how do I call the /hello endpoint in my cron job every day?
Can you help me?

Why exactly are you using Hono? Do you have something too complex to make without it?
